# Pandas force reindex duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want reindex dataframe's rows by specific column, let's say that dataframe contain column `colX`. That's mean I need call method `df.set_index(colX)`

Consider df.head() is

```
colX colY
2.71 foo1
3.14 foo2
6.9 foo3
6.9 foo4
9.6 foo5
```

When I reindex it

```
df=df.set_index('colX')
df2=df.reindex(index=[9.6,6.9,6.9,3.14,2.71])
```

I expect the result `df2.head()` is

```
colX colY
9.6 foo5
6.9 foo3 # duplicate index in colX
6.9 foo4 # duplicate index in colX
3.14 foo2
2.71 foo1
```

Or this

```
colX colY
9.6 foo5
6.9 foo4 # duplicate index in colX
6.9 foo3 # duplicate index in colX
3.14 foo2
2.71 foo1
```

Reindex won't work if there's duplicate axis.

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Note: df was created by `df=pd.read_csv('foobar.csv')`

Comment: Not sure why you need `reindex`. I'd rather do `df.sort_values('colX', ascending=False)`

Comment: @QuangHoang i know i can use method ```sort_values```, but unfortunately my school task doesn't allow me to use that. Actually yes my school task is about sorting algorithm, that's why I need itterate manually for custom sorting algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error means there is at least one duplicated values, so `reindex` raise error, because working only with unique values in list passed to `reindex`.

---

Solution with helper column created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('colX').cumcount()

L = [9.6,6.9,6.9,3.14,2.71]

df11 = pd.DataFrame({'colX': L})
df11['g'] = df11.groupby('colX').cumcount()
print (df11)
   colX  g
0  9.60  0
1  6.90  0
2  6.90  1
3  3.14  0
4  2.71  0

df = df.merge(df11, on=['colX','g'])
print (df)
   colX  colY  g
0  2.71  foo1  0
1  3.14  foo2  0
2  6.90  foo3  0
3  6.90  foo4  1
4  9.60  foo5  0
```

Or with `reindex`:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('colX').cumcount()

L = [9.6,6.9,6.9,3.14,2.71]

df11 = pd.DataFrame({'colX': L})
df11['g'] = df11.groupby('colX').cumcount()
print (df11)

df=df.set_index(['colX', 'g']).reindex(df11.set_index(['colX','g']).index)
print (df)
        colY
colX g      
9.60 0  foo5
6.90 0  foo3
     1  foo4
3.14 0  foo2
2.71 0  foo1
```

---

Wrong first solution:

```
df=df.set_index('colX')
df2=df.loc[[9.6,6.9,6.9,3.14,2.71]]
print (df2)
      colY
colX      
9.60  foo5
6.90  foo3 > combinations of 6.9 (2 times in original * 2 times in list = 4)
6.90  foo4
6.90  foo3
6.90  foo4
3.14  foo2
2.71  foo1
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my end. It duplicates both of the `6.9`.

Comment: Why there's g collumn?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira - because duplicates, for correct match.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira - added to answer.

Comment: @jezrael actually ```colX``` is not mandatory to being label or index in my school task, Can't you reset index with default index ```(0,1,2,3,4,5...)``` ? since it's not mandatory so the question maybe changed to ```reindexing dataframe's rows by specific collumn instead of using index```

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira - yop, if does not matter use first or second solution.

Comment: My main purpose actually is sorting ```colX``` for my school project with my own function or custom sorting. My function  return sorted list from ```colX``` (type data is list). Now all I need to do is reindex from my sorted list.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira - I understand, my answer explain how do it if duplicates. If no duplicates then original solution in question working perfectly.

Comment: I added ```df=df.reset_index()``` then ```df=df.drop('g',axis=1)```  to make dataframe like what i expected